# I can't log in to chat

Tags: support, chat

I keep getting this error:

> Your login data seems too old; please log in to any StackExchange site, possibly logging out before.

I have cleared my cookies, and logged in and out of EL&U several times. I have also closed and reopened my browser (Firefox 3.6.18) with no luck.  I have accessed chat with this computer and browser before.

Also, upgrading to Firefox 6.0.2 does not correct the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to have fixed itself after I left it resting on chat.stackexchange.com for several minutes (ten minutes or so).

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too, and as in your case, it started working all in a sudden. As far as I remember, I logged out of all the SE sites, not just EL&U. I think I also cleared all the browser data but the history, before visiting the chat.